# What does energy density state for holes in valence band mean and how is this equation applicable there?

Tags: density-of-states

[image]

Equation 1 is the energy density function for free particles confined in a 3D box. Now we could apply this equation to conduction band of a semiconducting material taking the electrons present there as free electrons but limited within the material; so resembling particles inside a 3D box.

But why so directly should function this form be applicable to the valence band? Aren’t the electrons localized over individual atoms there? Or do we only apply it there when current is present due to which electrons there too become free as in conduction band?

Even if this is the reason, and  if we wanted to find the total no of energy states lying between 0 to Ev (Ev=highest energy level in valence band), shouldn’t we just integrate Eqn 1 from 0 to Ev? Why is it instead Eqn 2 being integrated from -∞ to Ev?

But even before all of these questions, what does energy density for holes mean?